# How to modify a PostGIS function?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I wish to modify a PostGIS function `ST_PixelAsCentroids`. What is the best way to go *under-the-hood* of PostgreSQL/PostGIS functions and modify and customize them as you wish?

I'm not hitting the right keywords on Google it seems to find out and it would be great to have this on GIS.Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of functions... one's a regular sql function and another is a c function.

You can see which is which by doing:

```
=> \df+ ST_PixelAsCentroids
```

Postgres will tell you in the "Language" column.

For this particular case, it is a SQL function, and you can modify it using native `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...`

For C functions, you'll see the "Source Code" column a reference to the C function. Then you find it in PostGIS source that you can obtain from their site. For example, the `ST_PixelAsCentroids` SQL function uses the RASTER_getPixelPolygons C function, so you can look at the source file `raster/rt_pg/rt_pg.c` for this.

You'll, of course, need to recompile and reinstall PostGIS from source. It's probably a good idea to run the test suite again also. If your modifications are awesome, don't forget to contribute back! :)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like `ST_PixelAsCentroids()` is built upon `ST_PixelAsPolygon()` which is written in C code. Having very little experience programming in C it will be difficult to edit but I will have a look.

What is the complete path the to C files?

Comment: Even if you know C, it is difficult to simply dive into such a complicated system. You can find dev support by joining their dev mailing list. You can get the source from http://postgis.net/source and follow that relative path above to find that function you're looking for. Generally, you can do a unix `find/grep` to locate the source file for a particular function.

Comment: Phil,  I always find it helpful to look at the doxygen generated help e.g. http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.2/.  One of the PostGIS build bots generates it nightly. Both the 2.1 and 2.2 branch are listed on this page (as well as source tar balls) -- http://postgis.net/development  By navigating the doxygen code, you can see how the various functions call each other.